# Are there any interesting non-metrics whose open balls generate a topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be some set.
I am wondering if there are any interesting functions $\rho: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ whose open balls are the base for a topology on $X$, and where $\rho$ is not a metric (e.g. not symmetric, doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality).

I can think of one for the indiscreet topology ($\rho(x,y) \equiv 0$), but that is not very interesting.

Comment: How do you define open balls without a metric?

Comment: Ah, I guess you pull them back from $\mathbb R $ using the metric.

Answer (score 2):

The Minkowski metric on $\mathbb R^4$ is useful in relativity and is defined by $$\rho(x,y)=(x_1-y_1)^2-(x_2-y_2)^2-(x_3-y_3)^2-(x_4-y_4)^2.$$ Though it is called a metric, it is not really a metric because it can take negative values, and the triangle inequality does not hold. Furthermore, $\rho(x,y)=0$ does not imply $x=y$. However, the topology generated by the open balls is the standard topology. I must confess though, the open balls do not form a basis, but rather a sub-basis for the topology.

Answer (score 0):

If you drop the requirement that $d(x,y)=0$ implies $x=y$, you have a [pseudometric space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space). The open balls generate a topology which typically is not $T_0$.